# Building ARM64 ASM in Visual Studio with CMake

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, cmake, arm

I'm working on a cross-platform project which has some hand-written assembly to optimize performance for various CPU architectures. I'm converting this project to CMake from a proprietary build system, starting with compiling using Visual Studio on Windows. For x86 and AMD64, I've been able to assemble and link everything just fine, but I can't get it to work on ARM64 (or presumably ARM32, though I haven't tried that yet).

I'm including the ASM files in my sources as follows:

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "AMD64")
    list(APPEND SOURCES
        amd64/aesasm.asm
        ...)
    set_source_files_properties(
        amd64/aesasm.asm
        ...
        PROPERTY LANGUAGE ASM_MASM)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "X86")
    # ...
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "ARM64")
    list(APPEND SOURCES
        arm64/fdef_asm.asm
        ...)
    set_source_files_properties(
        arm64/fdef_asm.asm
        ...
        PROPERTY LANGUAGE ASM_MASM)
```

Then in my top-level CMakeLists.txt, I enable MASM using `enable_language(ASM_MASM)`. For x86 and AMD64, CMake automatically finds ml/ml64.exe, configures the Visual Studio project correctly, and everything works.

But for ARM64, if I try the same thing, I get this error from Visual Studio when trying to build: `MSB3721: The command "echo MASM not supported on this platform`. As far as I can tell, this is because Visual Studio considers ARM assembly to be a different dialect, "MARMASM", with a different executable name for the assembler (armasm/armasm64.exe).

I tried setting `enable_language(ASM_MARMASM)` in my ARM64 toolchain file, but CMake does not recognize this as an ASM dialect, and gives me this error:

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineASM_MARMASMCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: F:/os/src/symcrypt/bin/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CMakeASM_MARMASMCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (enable_language):
No CMAKE_ASM_MARMASM_COMPILER could be found.
```

I also tried manually setting the assembler:

```
get_filename_component(VS_TOOLS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_LINKER} DIRECTORY)
find_file(ARM64_COMPILER "armasm64.exe" HINTS ${VS_TOOLS_DIRECTORY})
set(CMAKE_ASM_MARMASM_COMPILER ${ARM64_COMPILER})
enable_language(ASM_MARMASM)
message(STATUS "Manually set assembler to ${CMAKE_ASM_MARMASM_COMPILER}")
```

But this does not work either; I still get an error that `No CMAKE_ASM_MARMASM_COMPILER could be found.`

How can I include ARM/ARM64 assembly in my project?

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, did you ever fix that issue?

Comment: @lewurm I had to put this work on the backburner for a while. I'm coming back to it now, but I did not find a solution yet. I think the examples you pointed to in the .NET source code are the best available option for now, so I marked your answer as correct. Another possibility one of my colleagues suggested was to just use GAS via cygwin, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Mitch for getting back to me! I agree, using GAS wouldn't be my preferred solution either. Specifically, I'm not sure about its support to target AArch64 and COFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake 3.26 has support for it.

In [CMake 3.26 Release Notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.26/release/3.26.html#languages):

> - The `ASM_MARMASM` language was added to support the Microsoft ARM assembler language.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CMake (still) does not have support for this. I found some bits in the .NET source code to work around it:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f8f63b1fde85119c925313caa475d9936297b463/eng/native/functions.cmake#L173-L207

and

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f8f63b1fde85119c925313caa475d9936297b463/eng/native/configurecompiler.cmake#L611-L626

edit: As reference, here's the commit for a project I had this requirement for: https://dyncall.org/pub/dyncall/dyncall/rev/451299d50c1a